# Let $\{v1, v2, . . . , vn\}$ span $V$, and let $T:V→W$ be a linear transformation. Prove that $\{T(v_1),..., T(v_n)\}$ spans $W$ and $image(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I got the proof for $\{T(v_1), T(v_2), . . . , T(v_n)\}$ spanning $W$:

Since the $v_i$ spans $V$, given any $v ∈ V$, we can write $v = a_1v_1 + . . . + a_nv_n$ for some scalars $a_i ∈ F$. Applying $T$ to both sides, we have $T(v) = T(a_1v_1 + . . . + a_nv_n) = a_1T(v_1) + . . . + a_nT(v_n)$, by linearity of $T$.

Now $T(v) = w$ for some arbitrary vector $w ∈ W$. Thus we have $w = T(v) = a_1T(v_1) + . . . + a_nT(v_n)$, for any arbitrary vector $w ∈ W$, so $(T(v_1), . . . , T(v_n))$ spans $W$.

But I'm confused about how to do it for $image(T)$. I know that the image of a linear transformation is the span of the vectors of the linear transformation, but I'm not sure how to use that.

Comment: "Now $T(v)=w$ for some arbitrary vector $w\in W$." This does not hold if $w\notin{\rm image}(T)$. In other words, you indeed proved that $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$ spans ${\rm image}(T)$. However, I do not think that such set spans $W$ if $T$ is not assumed to be surjective (onto $W$).

Comment: Indeed, @BernardPan, what if $T$ is the zero-transformation?

Comment: @Lubin In this case, $T(v_i)=0$ for all $i$. Seems okay here.

Comment: But $\{0\}$ doesn’t span $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the second part is correct.  Consider the zero transformation, or one into a space of higher dimension.  Say, for instance, $T:\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb R^5$.  Then $T$ can't be surjective.

To prove the second part is easy by linearity and the fact that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ spans $V$.  For the image of $T$ is nothing but $T(V)$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on which part is correct and which is incorrect?

Comment: As noted by @Lubin and others, unless your mapping is surjective the first part won't be correct.  The second part is easily correct, since any element of $V$ is a linear combo of the $v_i$.